# "does not necessarily outlive the lifetime" issue

Tags: rust, lifetime

My goal is to have a `Store` which contains various `Entry` items. The `Entry` items can live longer than the store itself, and so `Store` keeps a `Vec<&Entry>` ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5173bee1a59759e3879095b69ae11b76)):

```rust
struct Entry {
    title: String,
    content: String,
}

struct Store<'a> {
    // name: String,
    entries: Vec<&'a Entry>,
}

impl<'a> Store<'a> {
    fn new() -> Store<'a> {
        Store {
            // name,
            entries: Vec::new(),
        }
    }

    fn add_entry(self: &mut Store, entry: &Entry) {
        self.entries.push(entry);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let entry = Entry {
        title: "my title",
        content: "my content",
    };
    let mut store = Store::new();
    store.add_entry(entry);
}
```

```
error[E0308]: mismatched `self` parameter type
  --> src/main.rs:19:24
   |
19 |     fn add_entry(self: &mut Store, entry: &Entry) {
   |                        ^^^^^^^^^^ lifetime mismatch
   |
   = note: expected struct `Store<'a>`
              found struct `Store<'_>`
note: the anonymous lifetime #2 defined on the method body at 19:5...
  --> src/main.rs:19:5
   |
19 |     fn add_entry(self: &mut Store, entry: &Entry) {
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: ...does not necessarily outlive the lifetime `'a` as defined on the impl at 11:6
  --> src/main.rs:11:6
   |
11 | impl<'a> Store<'a> {
   |      ^^

error[E0308]: mismatched `self` parameter type
  --> src/main.rs:19:24
   |
19 |     fn add_entry(self: &mut Store, entry: &Entry) {
   |                        ^^^^^^^^^^ lifetime mismatch
   |
   = note: expected struct `Store<'a>`
              found struct `Store<'_>`
note: the lifetime `'a` as defined on the impl at 11:6...
  --> src/main.rs:11:6
   |
11 | impl<'a> Store<'a> {
   |      ^^
note: ...does not necessarily outlive the anonymous lifetime #2 defined on the method body at 19:5
  --> src/main.rs:19:5
   |
19 |     fn add_entry(self: &mut Store, entry: &Entry) {
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

[Error E0308](https://doc.rust-lang.org/error-index.html#E0308) is not very helpful in this case.

I don't understand why the lifetime at the `add_entry` method must outlive the one of the `impl`, which is what I understand from the error.

I am sure this is something quite basic, but I cannot figure it out by reading *The Rust Programming Language* up to chapter 15.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fixing the errors to make it compile: `add_entry` should look like this:

```
fn add_entry(&mut self, entry: &'a Entry) {
    self.entries.push(entry);
}
```

I.e. you must specify the lifetime of `entry` explicitly. Your `Store` assumes that its `Entry`s have a certain lifetime. If `add_entry` does not explicitly store this lifetime, Rust tries to infer automatic lifetimes - and it cannot prove that `entry`'s lifetime is actually the one your `Store` requires.

If you left `add_entry` as you did, you could essentially call it like this `store.add_entry(&Entry{...})` (i.e. you could pass a reference to a *temporary* entry). This temporary entry would go out of scope/be after the statement. Thus, Rust disallows to put it into `entries`, as it would then point to a already dropped (read: invalid) value.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4cf231d0d86ad819d584e0c3aca971f7)

Comment: OP would probably be helped by an explanation of **why**. Otherwise they are left to cargo cult arbitrary changes.

Comment: Thanks @phimuemue, that works. Can you please explain what the error "does not necessarily outlive the lifetime" mean here. I'd like to understand the deeper mechanisms here. In particular I don't get the relationship between the lifetime declared in the function and the one declared in the `impl`. I'll be happy to read any docs if can provide a link. Thanks.